# Is there any API access to Google Translate's "Did you mean" functionality?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translate, google-cloud-translate

I'd like to fully use Google Translate as an API, and of course their official Cloud Translation service basically does this. But recently I noticed one small difference: in the browser, Google TL may detect typos / small errors and automatically correct them and translate the correction.

For example:

[image]

As you can see, it says "Showing translation for "**testing**" rather than `testin`. So there's a step here where it automatically detects the mistake and chooses to translate its own corrected version instead (thus resulting in a correct translation).

If you click the "Translate instead", here's the result:

[image]

Google's Cloud Translation API shows the second result (i.e. "testin" instead of "tester"). I've done some searching and can't find this "did you mean" corrective functionality anywhere in Google Cloud, do they not provide it? I know I can build my own spellchecker and try it that way, but what I'm looking for specifically here is to just fully mimic Google Translate's behavior for a typical user.

Answer (score 1):

```
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()
result= translator.translate("testin if this works",src="en", dest='fr')
result.extra_data['possible-mistakes']
```

Output:
['***testing*** if this works',
'testing if this works',
[1],
None,
None,
False]

Answer (score 0):

Going further, this is a very **simple** and accurate example, but is insufficient. The user must be able to hide/disable these recommendations for contextual clarifications. Google is not my teacher, but my servant, like it or not.